# PrimeFaces confirmDialog not working with InternetExplorer

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 3.2 on WebSphere Application Server 8 with MyFaces 2.0.2.

I have an confirmDialog which works fine in Firefox.
But when I want to use it with Internet Explorer (Version 6,7,8) I cant use it, because the layer which should obscure the background also obscure the confirmDialog.

Does anyone know a solution?

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `appendToBody="true"` to your `p:confirmDialog` ,

also... is it inside a `Tab` or something ? cause taking it out should solve your issue too...

Try to re model your page so that the form will be inside the dialog and not the opposite....

something like this [Re: Problem: Dialog nested dialog with modal=true](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=19001#p59289)

Comment: I have tried with appendToBody = "true" but nothing changed. It is only in a <h:form>

Comment: confirmDialog does not have an attribute called modal

Comment: Without modal or modal = false in dialog it works fine. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. modal ? b.t.w  did you used p:confirmDialog or p:dialog ?

Comment: Thank you, first i used confirmDialog, now I switched to dialog

Comment: +1 You saved me a lot of frustration. My issue was needing appendToBody="true".